# Как сохранить ArrayList в SQLite android?

Tags: android, sql, массивы, sqlite, arraylist

Доброго времени суток.
Начал осваивать БД и столкнулся с задачей: как вставить в таблицу ArrayList?
Если не сложно, пожалуйста, с примером. Или покидайте какие-нибудь классные ссылки на SQLite, где описан данный процесс. Заранее благодарю =)

Comment: Весь List в одну запись или каждый элемент List -одна запись?

Comment: В каждую строку БД свой List со своими записями. Один-ко-многим, кажется, так

Comment: А что находится в этом List, какие данные и какого типа?

Comment: int, int, String, String, boolean - 5 переменных для каждой записи List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы в реляционную базу данных записать структуру, как многомерный массив, потребуется связь один ко многим.

Разберем пример. У нас есть список студентов, к каждому студенту нужно прикрепить имеющиеся у него документы (их может быть разное количество и наименование). Каждый документ имеет название и номер серии - условия эквивалентны прикреплению к записи (студенты) коллекции ArrayList (список документов) с несколькими полями (название и серия).

Создадим две таблицы - таблицу *names* с именами студентов и таблицу *documents* со списком документов:

таблица *names*:

```
| _id | name  |  
|-----|-------|  
| 1   | Настя |  
| 2   | Петя  |  
| 3   | Вася  |
```

Таблица *documents*:

```
| _id | document | number | key |
|-----|----------|--------|-----|
| 1   | Паспорт  | 156    | 1   |
| 2   | Права    | 187    | 1   |
| 3   | Полис    | 109    | 1   |
| 4   | Паспорт  | 205    | 2   |
| 5   | Полис    | 267    | 2   |
| 6   | Паспорт  | 387    | 3   |
| 7   | Страхока | 345    | 3   |
```

В таблице *documents* добавляем служебное поле *key*, которое будет связывать наши таблицы. В этом поле указывается ID студента из таблицы *names*, которому принадлежит данный документ (например, документы с номерами 205 и 267 принадлежат Пете).

Все готово. Теперь, чтобы получить, какие документы принадлежат Насте (получить содержиое `ArrayList` закрепленное за определенной записью) составляем такой запрос:

```
 SELECT  d.number, d.document FROM names n, documents d WHERE n.[name] = "Настя" AND n.[_id] = d.[key]
```

Получим выборку вида:

```
| number | document |
|--------|----------|
| 156    | Паспорт  |
| 187    | Права    |
| 109    | Полис    |
```

Строка с запросом читается так: Выбрать столбцы *number* и *document* из таблицы *documents* поиском по таблицам *documents* и *names* для которых совпадает условие: в таблице *names* столбец *name* = "Настя" и в таблице *documents* столбец *key* совпадает со столбцом *_id* таблицы *name*. На простом человечьем это значит, что мы просим отобрать из двух таблиц те значения, где для первой есть имя Настя, а для второй ее столбец *key* = столбцу *_id* отобранных для первой таблицы.
Подставляя в запрос другие имена (Петя, Вася ..) мы получим документы уже этих студентов.
PS: *n* и *d* - алиасы таблиц, для укорочения записи запросов, их можно не указывать, а писать полные имена таблиц.

Можем включить в выборку и имя студента (добавить данные из записи, к которой привязан список):

```
SELECT d.number, d.document, n.name FROM names n, documents d WHERE n.[name] = "Настя" AND n.[_id] = d.[key]
```

Получаем:

```
| number | document | name  |
|--------|----------|-------|
| 156    | Паспорт  | Настя |
| 187    | Права    | Настя |
| 109    | Полис    | Настя |
```

Чтобы "прикрепить" новый набор документов к определенной записи (записать `ArrayList`), нужно получить *_id* этой записи (таблица *names*) и добавить данные из списка в таблицу *documents*, в столбец *key* этой таблицы указывать полученный *_id* нужной записи.

Чтобы узнать намного больше рекомендую почитать замечательную книгу:

Бейли Л. - Изучаем SQL (Бестселлеры O'Reilly) - 2012г.

В этой книге очень доступно объясняется организация базы данных, все типы связей и составление всевозможных запросов. В отличие от прочих изданий по этой теме, запутанных и непонятных, данная книга будет просто незаменима для новичка.

Comment: Ух ты, спасибо большое за такое подробное пояснение! Книгу обязательно прочитаю =)