# Сохранение массива в sqlite

Tags: android, база-данных

Есть структура

```
class Export{
    class Item{
        String name;
        int size;
    }

    long time;
    String number;
    Item[] items;
}
```

И есть желание сохранять Export в базе данных. Видятся следующие варианты:

1. использовать SQLite

В базе создается таблица каждая запись в которой имеет поле с уникальным автогенерируемым идентификатором записи, поле для Export.time и поле для Export.number. А вот Export.items в эту таблицу не поместить. Для этих значений создается вторая таблица, каждая запись в которой содержит поле с идентификатором, полем для Item.name и полем для Item.size. Поле с идентификатором содержит идентификатор записи из первой таблицы и по нему можно выбрать все записи, которые относятся к массиву items конкретной записи из первой таблицы.

2. опять же использовать SQLite, но items сохранять в первой таблице в поле типа TEXT, предварительно конвертировав массив items в json.
3. использовать что-то еще

Вопрос в том, какой вариант правильный, первый или второй. И какие есть третьи варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант зависит от задачи.

Если предполагается, что структура "железобетонная", то лучше применить какой-нибудь ORM в которой каждое поле БД соотнесено полю класса. Я бы лично предпочел использовать [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com), там с помощью аннотаций довольно просто можно сгенерировать таблицы БД соответствующие вашей структуре данных и далее можно уже напрямую работать с Java объектом `Export` читать и писать в БД без проблем. Минус такого подхода состоит в том, что как только вы захотите модифицировать структуру `Export` вам немедленно придется модифицировать структуру таблиц - а это знаете ли боль... - придется в `SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade()` прописывать всякие разные хитрые операции.

Если же предполагается, что структура `Export` далее будет часто модифицироваться/обогащаться, что здесь лучше выбрать второй вариант, с сохранением в БД JSon строки.

Есть и третий вариант, воспользоваться стандартным механизмом Java реализуемым через интерфейс `Serializable` чтение/запись через `ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream` - [подробнее здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/60317/) - способ древний, работающий, но с тучей проблем - не советую.

Comment: сохранять массивы в БД, как json-строки, пожалуй худшее решение из всех возможных. Это крайне медленно, громоздко, ведет к лишнему коду и не имеет никаких преимуществ. Не могли бы вы пояснить, чем, с вашей точки зрения, такое решение лучше "академического" отношения один ко многим, принятого в реляционных БД для решения такой задачи уже не один десяток лет? ORMLite тоже не лучший выбор ORM, когда есть "чистый" (а не надстройка над SQLite с анотациями) Realm или ObjectBox, к примеру (в которых и изменение структуры объектов не боль)

Comment: @pavlofff я уже объяснял в чем преимущество json подхода, при модификации структуры данных структура БД не меняется. Realm конечно крут, но его Java инкарнация работает только в варианте Android и не поддерживает десктоп Java.

Comment: Вынужден не согласиться. Проработка структуры БД - первый шаг проектирования и изменение ее структуры как бы и не предполагается, если считать такой аргумент приемлемым, то использование SQLite вообще нужно исключить, так как тогда возможно изменение таблиц не только сохранения массива, но и "основных". О десктопной Java в вопросе речи и не идет, не вижу здесь препятствия.

Comment: @pavlofff как бы вы ни проектировали, все равно через какое-то время выясняется, что надо бы добавить поле, а то и целый класс - это жизнь, это agile. Вот сколько я работаю только и приходится непрерывно модифицировать казавшиеся незыблемыми на этапе проектирования данные. После релиза, прога начинает жить своей жизнью и юзеры чего-то начинают требовать/просить - многократно проходил это на своем опыте. По-поводу Realm vs. OrmLite - здесь на вкус и цвет товарищей нет. Я пару лет назад довольно подробно сканировал рынок ORM и остановился на OrmLite именно из-за его кросс-платформенности.

Comment: Все же вы меня не убедили и я бы по прежнему выбрал скорость и чистоту кода против "удобства" модификации БД. Как бы есть софт, который должен работать по возможности лучше и есть личные проблемы программиста, как лень модифицировать структуру БД. Пользователи, в общем то, не должны расчитываться за удобства для кодера.

Comment: Я не настаиваю :) Наш мир прекрасен тем, что каждый может иметь свое собственное мнение. Но как крючок оставлю мысль: одной из причин популярности noSQL как раз являются проблемы которые мы обсуждали. Одной из...

Comment: @Barmaley Согласен с вами без этого не обойтись после релиза пришлось изменить БД многое добавилось вечно им чегото не хатает

Comment: Все же я не понял, почему защитить от изменения структуры БД нужно именно сохранение массива, а не всю структуру, то есть почему ожидаются просьбы юзеров об изменении именно с массивами и почему тогда не предложит вовсе отказаться от БД в пользу JSON

Comment: @Barmaley Спасибо. Возьму ORM на изучение. А пока остановлюсь на варианте с двумя таблицами.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с данными в виде объектов есть ORM, как [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) или [ObjectBox](http://objectbox.io), которые сохраняют и получают данные напрямую в виде объектов, в том числе и массивов.

В реляционных БД, как SQLite, правильный первый вариант, в дисциплине СУБД это называется - [отношение один ко многим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631496/177345).

Так же вы можете сохранять массив и в виде JSON-строки, конечно. Но такое решение хуже первых двух вариантов, так как ничего кроме существенного замедления работы (медленный Java-код обработки в циклах + парсинг JSON, против моментальных запросов к БД), большое количество сопровождающего исключительно это решение дополнительного кода (и скорее всего даже доп.библиотеки типа GSON) против одной строки на выборку из БД и др.

PS: Так же в Android есть класс "псевдо" ORM типа ORMLite, ActiveAndroid, SugarORM и др. которые реализуются, как надстройки над реляционной SQLite (Realm и OB - "читстые" ORM с собственным низкоуровневым движком). Такие ORM имеют недостаток, как низкая (по сравнению с SQLite и "чистой" ORM) скорость работы, так как уходит время на трансляцию из реляционной структуры в объектную и некоторое количество костылей, чтобы свести эти два "мира" (реляционный и объектов) в одной сущности (как кодогенерация в некоторых из них, что делает создание струкуры БД несколько "необычным"). Это иногда приводит к неожиданным проблемам, где их не ждали.
В последнее время Google продвигает собственное решение ORM на базе SQLite - [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html), мнения по которому традиционно разделились.

Comment: Спасибо. Возьму ORM на изучение. А пока остановлюсь на варианте с двумя таблицами.